# scroll() and scrollTop() not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'd like to create a 'go-to-top'-button via jquery - but scroll() and scrollTop() aren't working...

Here's my setup:

```
<div id="go_top">go to top</div>
```

and CSS

```
#go_top {
position: fixed;
right: 2em;
bottom: 2em;
color: #000;
background-color: rgba(167, 204, 35, 0.6);
font-size: 12px;
padding: 1em;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
}
#go_top:hover {
color: #000;
background-color: rgba(167, 204, 35, 1);
}
```

Therefore, I setup the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#go_top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('#go_top').fadeOut(100);
        }
}


});
```

But it's not working. The div just won't show :(

Comment: Missing `);` for scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#go_top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('#go_top').fadeOut(100);
        }
}); // ')' is missing here**      
});
```

You are missing **')'** in your function.

Comment: the syntax trolled us all, again!

Comment: I will flag your answer as correct, but need to wait 3 more minutes

Comment: ahm may I ask you another thing?
How can I set the div to show when I scrolled down the page independent of the scrollTop() >'value' ?

Comment: @daftpanda, Please post this requirement as another question.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).scrollTop(); instead of $(this).scrollTop()

```
$(document).scroll(function () { alert($(document).scrollTop()) });
```

Comment: $(document).scroll(function () {
  alert($(document).scrollTop())
 }); it works for me, i test it now

Comment: got it to work - RGS' answer helped me out here ;) But thank you very much for your engagement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code having Missing `);` and errors scroll top return value pnly

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(this).scrollTop())
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { // not px it returns value
            $('#go_top').fadeIn(100);
        } else {
            $('#go_top').fadeOut(100);
        }
    }); // here you must close
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/90/) (Scroll and check)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#go_top').fadeIn(100);
        } else {
            $('#go_top').fadeOut(100);
            }     

    });    
});
```

you are missing one closing brace and remove the px from 200